# Change intervals based on index in LESS

Tags: less

I want to change the factor by which the value is calculated inside the loop in LESS.

Right now my code is

```
@names:
    1q, 
    half, 
    3q,
    one,
    two,
    three,
    four,
    five,
    six,
    seven,
    eight;

.margin(8);

.margin(@n, @i: 1) when (@i =< 4) {
  @name: extract(@names, @i);
  .space-@{name}, .space-@{name}-top { margin-top: @i * 0.25rem !important; }
  .space-@{name}, .space-@{name}-bottom { margin-top: @i * 0.25rem !important; }
  .margin(@n, (@i + 1));
}
```

Which produces:

```
.space-1q,
.space-1q-top {
  margin-top: 0.25rem !important;
}
.space-1q,
.space-1q-bottom {
  margin-top: 0.25rem !important;
}
.space-half,
.space-half-top {
  margin-top: 0.5rem !important;
}
.space-half,
.space-half-bottom {
  margin-top: 0.5rem !important;
}
.space-3q,
.space-3q-top {
  margin-top: 0.75rem !important;
}
.space-3q,
.space-3q-bottom {
  margin-top: 0.75rem !important;
}
.space-one,
.space-one-top {
  margin-top: 1rem !important;
}
.space-one,
.space-one-bottom {
  margin-top: 1rem !important;
}
```

I want from the 5th iteration, to be like `.space-@{name}, .space-@{name}-top { margin-top: @i * 1rem !important; }` instead `0.25`.

Is it possible to include another `when` inside the loop? Or I should just use another function?

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to include another `when` inside the loop?

Yes, it is (there's no restriction on nesting mixins/rulesets and each may have a guard).
However in this case it will be less bloating and more consistent to provide these values directly in the array itself rather than hardcoding for specific indices:

```
@numb3rs:
    1q   1/4,
    half 1/2,
    3q   3/4,
    one   1,
    two   2,
    three 3,
    four  4,
    five  5,
    six   6,
    seven 7,
    eight 8;

.margin();
.margin(@i: length(@numb3rs)) when (@i > 0) {
    .margin(@i - 1);
    @item: extract(@numb3rs, @i);
    @key:  extract(@item, 1);
    .space-@{key} {
        margin: 1rem * extract(@item, 2);
    }
}
```

It's even possible to get rid of the loop completely:

```
.numb3rs() {
    .-(1q,   1/4);
    .-(half, 1/2);
    .-(3q,   3/4);
    .-(one,   1);
    .-(two,   2);
    .-(three, 3);
    .-(four,  4);
    .-(five,  5);
    .-(six,   6);
    .-(seven, 7);
    .-(eight, 8);
}

.margin();
.margin() {
    .numb3rs();
    .-(@key, @value) {
        .space-@{key} {
            margin: 1rem * @value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just in case, I hope you realize that hardcoding such specific positioning in the markup is considered a very bad practice. And if it's really nesessary you can do it via plain vanilla HTML style attributes, e.g. `<p style="margin: 3rem">Foo</p>`. I.e. such CSS classes do not make sense in general case.